# Mongoose set default value and insert into database

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm really new to Mongo/Mongoose. The scenario is this: set and update default value upon finding all entries but I think I'm missing something

It is working on web view but it is not showing in database after finding multiple entries. I have to click on each entry on the web view to save it to database
[image]

[image]

```
var gcalbookingSchema = new Schema({

gcalId: String,
training: {type: String, default: "work out" },
summary: String,
email: String,
mobile: {type: String, default: "12345678" },
datetime: Date,
notification: {type: String, default: "24 hours" },
attendees:   [[]]
});
```

This is my codes to find multiple entries and display it on web view. I tried using **options** with **setDefaultsOnInsert: true** but it threw **callback.apply is not a function**

```
app.get("/api/gcal", function (req, res) {

var gemail = req.query.email;

var options = {
  // Return the document after updates are applied
  new: true,
  // Create a document if one isn't found. Required
  // for `setDefaultsOnInsert`
  upsert: true,
  setDefaultsOnInsert: true
};

GcalBooking.find({
  email: gemail
}, options, null, {
  sort: {
    datetime: 1
  }
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  res.status(200).json(result);

  for (let x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
    console.log(result[x].summary)
  }

});


})
```

Comment: I'd suggest to isolate server side problems from frontend and AngularJS. It's either one or another. If there are problems with Mongoose, they can be replicated with pure Node or Postman. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . *I tried using options with setDefaultsOnInsert: true* - where? Obviously, this is the one that should be used here.

Comment: I added the options back into the code. I suspect the keyword "find" is incorrect but if I use "findOneAndUpdate", it won't fulfill multiple entries. It's definitely server side problem because the data it able to be populated in frontend. I added the screenshot for context